# Tabbed navigation with image bleeding through

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to create a site with tabbed navigation with an image background that "bleeds through" the main div into the active tab. I made a little ASCII artwork to describe this:

`+-----------+-----------+-----------+

|/ / Tab 1 /| ! !Tab 2! | & &Tab 3& |

| / / / / / +-----------+-----------+----------------+

|/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / |

| / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /|

|/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / |

| / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /|

|/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / |

| / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /|

|/ / / / / / / Main div here / / / / / / / / / / / / |

| / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /|

|/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / |

| / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /|

|/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / |

| / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /|

|/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / |

| / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /|

|/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / |

| / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /|

+----------------------------------------------------+`

My attempt at a solution is as follows.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="nav">
            <a href="#home" class="L1 current">Tab 1 >></a><!--
         --><a href="#welcome" class="L2">Tab 2 >></a><!--
         --><a href="#setup" class="L3">Tab 3 >></a><!--
         --><div id="floater">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <br><br><br>Body conent here<br><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in style.css:

```
body { width: 650px; margin: auto; font: 12px "Arial", sans-serif; }
a { text-decoration: none; }

#body { background-image: url('bg.jpg'); }

#nav a, #nav div { display: inline-block; width: 90px; height: 18px; border: 1px black solid; color: black; background-color: #C7E9ED;}
#nav .current { background-color: transparent; border-bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 1px;}
#nav #floater { background-color: white; width: 375px; padding-top: 1px; border: 0; border-bottom: 1px black solid; }

#main { border: 1px black solid; border-top: 0px; text-align: center; }
```

But this isn't suitable for my needs, as I'm planning on also using these tabs as breadcrumb navigation, so it'll vary from page to page.

Is there a way to set the width of float to stretch from the last tab to the edge of nav? Or is there a better approach altogether?

Comment: Only because it strikes me as exactly the problem (don't mean to spam): Maybe look at the CSS source of wildcard.pinkgothic.com - looks like that approach might solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution to this that requires understanding the `background-position` property.

What you need to do is set a background image for each of the tabs, with `background-position: 0;`

For each page make sure that the correct background is set for the main region, but use `background-position: 0 -20px` You'll have set the background on both elements, but they should join seamlessly. You will of course need to adjust the y offset of the background position to whatever the (inner) height of the tab is.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's just better to set tabs container (with id='nav' in your case) background-color to the same with last tab?

Comment: Perhaps I should have made myself clearer. The background for the main div is an image, not a solid color.

Comment: hmm, sorry, i tried different ways for your problem, but see only one. since you know the width of entire div (650px) and two tabs with 90px width, so we can set the last one width to 650-90*2.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was hoping to be able to change the number of tabs across different pages without changing the markup.

Comment: in this case you need table-cell behavior (which is not cross-browser, unfortunately). or maybe just use <table> - there is no shame))